# Binding data If we have different views for portrait and LandScape Mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a complicated Screen. And my App supports both Landscape and Portrait mode. So I created two storyBoard for iPAD and iphone. Now How to bind the data if lets say user is in Portrait mode and he is filling some form. If he rotate his device and come to LandScape mode. How we can preserve and show that data in the LandScape View. Please help.